# React v6-Redux Create PrivateRoutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Im trying to create a PrivateRoutes in addition to the regular routes.
After login, the page is successfully re-direct to /home, however when I tried to open /work, the page will go back to /home.  all the data from state.valid is also shows "unidentified" in /work.

I figured it out that inside the privateRoutes it check if valid.isAuthenticated is true or not. However since.  valid.isAuthenticated is set to false as initial value in reducer,  everytime I open /home or /work, it re-render /login and then render /home or /work.

How do I fix to not to render /login before opening other pages?

Here is my PrivateRoutes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const valid = useSelector((state) => state.valid);
  return valid.isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

here is my AppRouter.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

import App from "../components/App";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import HomePage from "../components/HomePage";
import WorkPage from "../components/WorkPage";


const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <NavigationBar />
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} exact />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} exact />
          <Route path="/home" element={<PrivateRoute><HomePage /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/work" element={<PrivateRoute><WorkPage /></PrivateRoute>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
export default AppRouter;
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (valid.isAuthenticated) {
      navigate("/home");
    } 
  },[valid.isAuthenticated]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

import App from "../components/App";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import HomePage from "../components/HomePage";
import WorkPage from "../components/WorkPage";


const AppRouter = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!valid.isAuthenticated) {
            navigate("/login");
        }
    });

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <NavigationBar />
                <div>
                    {valid.isAuthenticated ? <>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" element={<App />} exact />
                            <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
                            <Route path="/work" element={<WorkPage />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </>
                        :
                        <>
                    <Routes>
                            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} exact />
                    </Routes>
                        </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )

};
export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i end up getting error  router.ts:11 No routes matched location "/login"